# Correctly presenting new scene in swift spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using spritekit with swift, and I'm just trying to present a new scene...but something is wrong and throwing errors.  I was pretty sure this was the right syntax, and this is really throwing me for a loop.

The line

```
    let skView = self.view as SKView
```

is giving me the error "SKView? is not convertible to SKView

Any advice is appreciated!
*my current code is below:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if(self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton)
            {
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView
                    // Configure the view.

                /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

                /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
                scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

The problem is the `view` property on `SKScene` is an optional (`SKView?`) because an `SKScene` doesn't necessarily have a containing view; what's it contained in before its been presented? Nothing.

To solve your problem you need to check the scene has a view by unwrapping the `view` property, by using optional binding for example:

```
if let view = self.view {
    let scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
    view.presentScene(scene)
}
```

You can be pretty certain your `SKScene` has been presented (and thus `view` isn't `nil`) if someone is pressing on it - therefore you could instead force unwrap `view`, like so:

```
let scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
view!.presentScene(scene)
```

Also, it's not required that you configure the `SKView` again (`skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true`) since this, presumably, was already done in `GameViewController`.

---

Edit:

The line `let skView = self.view as! SKView` is likely from `GameViewController` (a subclass of `UIViewController`). If you take a look at the documentation for [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/) and [`SKScene`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html) you'll see they both have a `view` property:

```
class UIViewController: /* Superclass and Protocols */ {
    var view: UIView!
    // ...
}

class SKScene: SKEffectNode {
    weak var view: SKView? 
    // ...
}
```

However their types differ which means the way you use them differs. In the case of `SKScene` see above about unwrapping. In the case of `UIViewController`, you need to cast to `SKView` with the line:

```
let skView = self.view as! SKView
```

because `UIView` doesn't have the methods necessary for presenting an `SKScene`. (For more information on casting I'd recommending you take a look at [The Swift Programming Language: Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338))

---

Normally you wouldn't be allowed to cast from `UIView` to `SKView` (keep in mind that `SKView` is a subclass of `UIView`). Try the following in Playgrounds:

```
let view = UIView()
let skView = view as! SKView
```

You should get an error something along the lines of:

> Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x1041d0eb0) to 'SKView'
>   (0x10da10718)

However you can cast from `UIView` to `SKView` in your `GameViewController` because the *Custom Class* of `GameViewController`'s `view` has been set to `SKView`:

[image]

I hope that helps clear up any confusion you had.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I didn't see this is that I don't really understand fully the significance of the line  let skView = self.view as SKView ... can you maybe explain why it was even suggested to appear in the first place (in my other googling), and why you didn't need to include it here?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

let sKView = self.view?.scene?.view

sKView?.presentScene(scene)

Best regards,
Yassine